# jest enzyme testing a component with async fetch to api

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, fetch, enzyme, jestjs

I'm using react, jest and enzyme with immutable. I'm trying to mount a component that fetching data from the API, and I'm having a little difficulties.

```
// FooListContainer.jsx

export default class FooListContainer extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
           foos: List()
        }
    }

    componetWillMount() { 
        manager.bringFooList()
        .then(lst => this.setState({ foos: fromJS(lst) }))
        .done();
    }

    render() {
        return <FooList foos={this.state.foos} />
    }
}
```

This is the ui component all it does is receive list and map them

```
// FooList.jsx

export default class FooList extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
           <div>
               {this.props.foos.map(item => <div>{item}</div>)}
           </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Now I would like to test the data received from the fetch in FooListContainter is passed correctly to FooList.

```
// FooListContainer.test.jsx

describe('rendering', () => {
    it('Should passed the data from the fetch to the FooList', () => {
        const response = ['1', '2', '3'];

        manager.bringFooList = jest.fn(() => {
           return new Promise(resolve => {
               return resolve(response);
           });
        })

        const wrapper = mount(<FooListContainer />);

        const fooList = wrapper.find(FooList);

        expect(fooList.props().foos.size).toBe(3);
    });
});
```

But the test fails because it expects the length to be 3 and it actual length is 0 from some reason.

I think that it has something to do with the fact that the fetch inside the container is async - so the test is not 'waiting' to the response and render is happening before the state change for the first time and the FooList receive an empty list.

I have tried to receive in the 'it' function an async callback as an argument and call it after the mount, like this:

```
// FooListContainer.test.jsx

describe('rendering', () => {
    it('Should passed the data from the fetch to the FooList', (done) => {
        const response = ['1', '2', '3'];

        manager.bringFooList = jest.fn(() => {
           return new Promise(resolve => {
               return resolve(response);
           });
        })

        const wrapper = mount(<FooListContainer />);
        done();

        const fooList = wrapper.find(FooList);

        expect(fooList.props().foos.size).toBe(3);
    });
});
```

But the above example did not work.
I would really appreciate every help you could give me.

Comment: I am having the same problem with async calls. Did you actually solved this?

Comment: Yes I was able to mock the promise and the use async and awiat on componentWillMount it solved it